# MySQLi + PHP safe insert doesn't work with WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This part works fine

```
    $stmt= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO books (title) VALUES (?)");
    $booktitle=$_POST['booktitle'];
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $booktitle);   // bind $sample to the parameter

// escape the POST data for added protection
$booktitle = isset($_POST['booktitle'])
          ? $db->real_escape_string($_POST['booktitle'])
          : '';


$stmt->execute();
```

This part doesn't work

```
$stmta= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO books (author) VALUES (?) WHERE title = '$booktitle' ");
$author=$_POST['author'];
$stmta->bind_param('s', $author);   // bind $sample to the parameter

// escape the POST data for added protection
$author = isset($_POST['author'])
          ? $db->real_escape_string($_POST['author'])
          : '';


$stmta->execute();
```

The issue is in using WHERE? I tried to use same code without WHERE, and it worked. How is right?

Comment: `insert into` without `select from` does not support `where`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the part that doesn't work?

Comment: @MarkBaker To insert second one in the same row

Comment: You can't [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) more than one record in the same row, every INSERT is to create a new row.... if you want to add a new column value or change a column value in an existing row, you use [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Comment: But don't use `$db->real_escape_string()` when you're using bind vars, else you're double escaping... a bind will automatically escape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **update** row not **insert** new one.

```
UPDATE books SET author = ? WHERE title = '$booktitle'
```

Additionally title should be bind too.